# How to print a certain line of a file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I don't have a decent text editor on this server, but I need to see what's causing an error on line 10 of a certain file. I do have PowerShell though...

Comment: what about `(get-content myfile.txt)[9]` ?

Comment: yes, the problem is that with big files can be really slow, 'cause all the file is read before return the [index]

Comment: I tried (get-content myfile.txt)[9] in Windows Powershell

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will show the 10th line of myfile.txt:

```
get-content myfile.txt | select -first 1 -skip 9
```

both `-first` and `-skip` are optional parameters, and `-context`, or `-last` may be useful in similar situations.

Comment: This will work well for small files. Unless something has changed, `Get-Content` will read the entire file into memory. That does not always work well with large files.

Answer (score 41):

It's as easy as using select:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Select-Object -Index (line - 1)
```

E.g. to get line 5

```
Get-Content file.txt | Select-Object -Index 4
```

Or you can use:

```
(Get-Content file.txt)[4]
```

Comment: wouldnt this reterive the whole content into memory first which is bad ?

Comment: See C.B.'s answer for performance stats (time, not memory). If you're working with large files, then this is inefficient. If you're using small and just a few files, then performance isn't that important. Sometimes clean code is more important. This answer is 5 years old - things have changed in powershell as well

Comment: @Stacker [@Lance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14760194/2518317) is the correct answer (so long as the line you need is toward the start of the file). Basically equivalent to 'nix' `head -n`

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `-TotalCount` parameter of the [`Get-Content` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849787.aspx) to read the first `n` lines, then use `Select-Object` to return only the `n`th line:

```
Get-Content file.txt -TotalCount 9 | Select-Object -Last 1;
```

Per the comment from @C.B. this should improve performance by only reading up to and including the `n`th line, rather than the entire file.  Note that you can use the aliases `-First` or `-Head` in place of `-TotalCount`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a function that uses .NET's [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/29kt2zfk.aspx) classes directly:

```
function GetLineAt([String] $path, [Int32] $index)
{
    [System.IO.FileMode] $mode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Open;
    [System.IO.FileAccess] $access = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read;
    [System.IO.FileShare] $share = [System.IO.FileShare]::Read;
    [Int32] $bufferSize = 16 * 1024;
    [System.IO.FileOptions] $options = [System.IO.FileOptions]::SequentialScan;
    [System.Text.Encoding] $defaultEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
    # FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare, Int32, FileOptions) constructor
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d0y914c5.aspx
    [System.IO.FileStream] $input = New-Object `
        -TypeName 'System.IO.FileStream' `
        -ArgumentList ($path, $mode, $access, $share, $bufferSize, $options);
    # StreamReader(Stream, Encoding, Boolean, Int32) constructor
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143458.aspx
    [System.IO.StreamReader] $reader = New-Object `
        -TypeName 'System.IO.StreamReader' `
        -ArgumentList ($input, $defaultEncoding, $true, $bufferSize);
    [String] $line = $null;
    [Int32] $currentIndex = 0;

    try
    {
        while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
        {
            if ($currentIndex++ -eq $index)
            {
                return $line;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Close $reader and $input
        $reader.Close();
    }

    # There are less than ($index + 1) lines in the file
    return $null;
}

GetLineAt 'file.txt' 9;
```

Tweaking the `$bufferSize` variable might affect performance.  A more concise version that uses default buffer sizes and doesn't provide optimization hints could look like this:

```
function GetLineAt([String] $path, [Int32] $index)
{
    # StreamReader(String, Boolean) constructor
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9y86s1a9.aspx
    [System.IO.StreamReader] $reader = New-Object `
        -TypeName 'System.IO.StreamReader' `
        -ArgumentList ($path, $true);
    [String] $line = $null;
    [Int32] $currentIndex = 0;

    try
    {
        while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
        {
            if ($currentIndex++ -eq $index)
            {
                return $line;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        $reader.Close();
    }

    # There are less than ($index + 1) lines in the file
    return $null;
}

GetLineAt 'file.txt' 9;
```

Comment: Overengineering: See BACON's solution on SO for a quick way to read a text file. :)

Comment: I stumbled on this question while looking for how to do this for a **large** file - exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Tao Thank you.  Glad _someone_ found this useful.  Sometimes the built-in PowerShell cmdlets don't give you the control or efficiency you need, especially, like you said, when working with large files.

Comment: +1 For Northben's (funny) explanation for overengineering. +1 For Bacon for his effort.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here some test:

```
# Added this for @Graimer's request ;) (not same computer, but one with HD little more
# performant...)
> measure-command { Get-Content ita\ita.txt -TotalCount 260000 | Select-Object -Last 1 }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 28
Milliseconds      : 893
Ticks             : 288932649
TotalDays         : 0,000334412788194444
TotalHours        : 0,00802590691666667
TotalMinutes      : 0,481554415
TotalSeconds      : 28,8932649
TotalMilliseconds : 28893,2649


> measure-command { (gc "c:\ps\ita\ita.txt")[260000] }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 9
Milliseconds      : 257
Ticks             : 92572893
TotalDays         : 0,000107144552083333
TotalHours        : 0,00257146925
TotalMinutes      : 0,154288155
TotalSeconds      : 9,2572893
TotalMilliseconds : 9257,2893


> measure-command { ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("c:\ps\ita\ita.txt"))[260000] }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 234
Ticks             : 2348059
TotalDays         : 2,71766087962963E-06
TotalHours        : 6,52238611111111E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,00391343166666667
TotalSeconds      : 0,2348059
TotalMilliseconds : 234,8059



> measure-command {get-content .\ita\ita.txt | select -index 260000}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 36
Milliseconds      : 591
Ticks             : 365912596
TotalDays         : 0,000423509949074074
TotalHours        : 0,0101642387777778
TotalMinutes      : 0,609854326666667
TotalSeconds      : 36,5912596
TotalMilliseconds : 36591,2596
```

the winner is : `([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines( path ))[index]`

Comment: how about @Bacon 's answer ? since you already have a sample file :-)

Comment: @Graimer Added :). All this test are intended for seeking in a big file for big index, I think that for little index's value the results may vary. Each test was done in a new powershell session to avoid HD pre-caching features.

Comment: I'm really surprised that `ReadAllLines()` is not only faster, but so much faster than the two uses of `Get-Content`.  As the name suggests, it's reading the entire file, too.  Anyways, I posted another approach, if you want to try that one, too.  Also, whenever I use `Measure-Command` to benchmark code I usually run it like this `1..10 | % { Measure-Command { ... } } | Measure-Object TotalMilliseconds -Average -Min -Max -Sum;` so I can get a more accurate number from multiple test runs.

Comment: I get this error:
```Exception calling "ReadAllLines" with "1" argument(s): "Array dimensions exceeded supported range." At line:1 char:1```

Answer (score 3):

To reduce memory consumption and to speed up the search you may use -ReadCount option of Get-Content cmdlet (https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh849787.aspx).

This may save hours when you working with large files.

Here is an example:

```
$n = 60699010
$src = 'hugefile.csv'
$batch = 100
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$count = 0
Get-Content $src -ReadCount $batch -TotalCount $n | %  { 
    $count += $_.Length
    if ($count -ge $n ) {
        $_[($n - $count + $_.Length - 1)]
    }
}

$timer.Stop()
$timer.Elapsed
```

This prints $n'th line and elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but despite being one of the most viewed ones for this topic, none of the answers are completely satisfactory to me. `Get-Content` is easy to use, but it shows its limitations when it comes to really large text files (e.g. >5 GB).

I figured out a solution which does not require the entire file to be loaded into main memory and that is way faster than `Get-Content` (almost as fast as `sed` on Linux, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327690/3328545)):

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::ElementAt([System.IO.File]::ReadLines("<path_to_file>"), <index>)
```

This takes about 4 seconds on my machine to find a line in the middle of a ~4.5 GB file, whereas `(Get-Content -Path <path_to_file> -TotalCount <index>)[-1]` takes about 35 seconds.