# Get specific line from text file using just shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to get a specific line from a text file.

So far, online I have only seen stuff like sed, (I can only use the sh -not bash or sed or anything like that). I need to do this only using a basic shell script.

```
cat file | while read line
    do
       #do something
    done
```

I know how to iterate through lines, as shown above, but what if I just need to get the contents of a particular line

Comment: do you know the line number?

Comment: Then you get to count.

Comment: yes, the line number is 5 @MehulRathod

Comment: this is my first week of shell script, so I am still learning the basics

Comment: heres what i would do where foo is my file name  line=`cat foo | head -n 5 | tail -1`

Comment: Why is `cat` okay but `sed` is not?  That makes no sense.

Comment: Because no-one can say no to `cat`. Aw... cute `cat`!

Answer (score 270, accepted):

sed:

```
sed '5!d' file
```

awk:

```
awk 'NR==5' file
```

Comment: What about with the sh command, I cannot use sed, awk. I should make this more clear in the question.

Comment: @GangstaGraham you said you know how to iterate through lines, how about adding a counter? if the counter reaches your target line number, get the line and break the loop. does it help?

Comment: yeah, i guess so, sh in general is kind of confusing though

Comment: @Kent what is 5!d here ..? and how to use this lineNumebr as a variable in shell script ..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar read sed's info page. `5!d` means delete all lines except 5.  shell var is possible, you need double quotes.

Comment: I would suggest adding another variant: `sed -n 5p` This seems more logical to remember for newbies, because `-n` means "no output by default" and `p` stands for "print", and there's no potentially confusing mention of deleting (when people talk of files, deleting lines tends to mean something different).

Comment: @JosipRodin you are right, `-n '5p'` works for this problem too.  The difference here is, with `5!d` you can add `-i` to write the change back to the file. however, with `-n 5p` you have to `sed -n '5p'  f > f2&&  mv f2 f` again, for this question, I am agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 36):

Assuming `line` is a variable which holds your required line number, if you can use `head` and `tail`, then it is quite simple:

```
head -n $line file | tail -1
```

If not, this should work:

```
x=0
want=5
cat lines | while read line; do
  x=$(( x+1 ))
  if [ $x -eq "$want" ]; then
    echo $line
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: This `-eq` comparison is for integers, so it wants a line number, not line content (`$line`). This has to be fixed by defining e.g. `want=5` prior to the loop, and then using the `-eq` comparison on `$want`. [moved from a rejected edit]

Comment: @JosipRodin I made an independent edit suggestion based on your comment, as I agree with it. Hopefully this time it won't be rejected.

Comment: This is massively much slower than @faithonour 's solution below

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods while using `sed` is obviously faster, it does not provide an answer to the question. If you missed it, the question explicitly states that `sed` is not usable, and `sh` is the only tool available.

Comment: True, he did accept the answer though! :-)

Answer (score 33):

You could use `sed -n 5p file`.

You can also get a range, e.g., `sed -n 5,10p file`.

Comment: How would you also bring x files after/before (context), like in `grep -C`? Would be useful to easily seek for errors on source code.

Answer (score 24):

**Best performance** method

```
sed '5q;d' file
```

Because `sed` stops reading any lines after the 5th one

*Update experiment from [Mr. Roger Dueck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1488762/roger-dueck)*

> I installed wcanadian-insane (6.6MB) and compared sed -n 1p /usr/share/dict/words and sed '1q;d' /usr/share/dict/words using the time command; the first took 0.043s, the second only 0.002s, so using 'q' is definitely a performance improvement!

Comment: This is also commonly written: `sed -n 5q`

Comment: I like this solution because `sed` stops reading any lines after the 5th one.

Comment: I installed wcanadian-insane (6.6MB) and compared `sed -n 1p /usr/share/dict/words` and `sed '1q;d' /usr/share/dict/words` using the `time` command; the first took 0.043s, the second only 0.002s, so using 'q' is definitely a performance improvement!

Comment: Warning: using `q` in a sed command from a pipe will result in `broken pipe`.  In that case, have to resort to `sed -n 5p`

Comment: @WilliamPursell `sed -n 5q` prints nothing for me. I think the answer is the best variant, but `sed -n '5{p;q}'` also works for me.

Answer (score 12):

If for example you want to get the lines 10 to 20 of a file you can use each of these two methods:

```
head -n 20 york.txt | tail -11
```

or

```
sed -n '10,20p' york.txt
```

`p` in above command stands for printing.

Here's what you'll see:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed` command.

If the preferred line number is 5:

```
sed -n '5p' filename #get the 5th line and prints the value (p stands for print)
```

If the preferred line number is a range, e.g. 1-5 lines:

```
sed -n '1,5p' filename #get the 1 to 5th line and prints the values
```

If need to get 1st and 5th line only, e.g. 1st Line, 5th Line:

```
sed -n '1p;5p;' filename #get the 1st and 5th line values only
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this sort of thing is to use external tools.  Disallowing the use of external tools while writing a shell script is absurd.  However, if you really don't want to use external tools, you can print line 5 with:

```
i=0; while read line; do test $((++i)) = 5 && echo "$line"; done < input-file
```

Note that this will print logical line 5.  That is, if `input-file` contains line continuations, they will be counted as a single line.  You can change this behavior by adding `-r` to the read command. (Which is probably the desired behavior.)

Comment: `$((++i))` appears to be a bashism; if the OP is restricted in using external tools, I wouldn't assume they'll have access to more than a plain `/bin/sh`

Comment: @JosipRodin No, it's a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04) feature (but support for `++` increments is specifically marked as optional).

Comment: @tripleee it doesn't work with modern dash as /bin/sh, so I would not rely upon it.

Comment: But a simple workaround like `$((i+=1))` works in Dash, too.

Comment: `$(($i+1))` is the simple workaround I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't particularly like any of the answers.

Here is how I did it.

```
# Convert the file into an array of strings
lines=(`cat "foo.txt"`)

# Print out the lines via array index
echo "${lines[0]}"
echo "${lines[1]}"
echo "${lines[5]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the question was asked for bash, here is the fastest simplest way to do this.

```
readarray -t a <file ; echo ${a[5-1]}
```

You may may discard array a when not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In parallel with [William Pursell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328958/874188), here is a simple construct which should work even in the original v7 Bourne shell (and thus also places where Bash is not available).

```
i=0
while read line; do
    i=`expr "$i" + 1`
    case $i in 5) echo "$line"; break;; esac
done <file
```

Notice also the optimization to `break` out of the loop when we have obtained the line we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
 line=$(sed "${i}q;d" file.txt)
 echo $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with perl! If you want to get line 1, 3 and 5 from a file, say /etc/passwd:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){if(++$l~~[1,3,5]){print}}' < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: `seq 5 | perl -ne 'print if $. ~~ [1, 4, 5]'` but smartmatch is experimental and it's use discouraged

Comment: Not a single one of the other solutions are this concise, or allows this much flexibility. (Why does it seem that everything that saves time and makes things easier, is "discouraged" by "smart people", are we all supposed to stare at screens all day?)

Comment: Glad to see some solution with perl which is a Swiss army knife for file filtering.
I would suggest small enhancement ->  `cat /etc/password | perl -ne 'next unless ++$l == 4; print'` if you are interested in one single line. 
To keep your flexibility without experimental -> `cat /etc/password | perl -ne 'next unless $ref{++$l}; print; BEGIN{ %ref = map{$_=>1} (1,4,5)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
line=5; prep=`grep -ne ^ file.txt | grep -e ^$line:`; echo "${prep#$line:}"
```

Comment: could you describe a little at least why this work to make it clearer to the person who asked the question?

Comment: So, the first grep selects all the lines adding line numbers at their beginnings. Then the second grep selects a specific line by matching the line number at start. And finally the line number is trimmed from the line start in echo.

Comment: This is both complex and inefficient compared to `sed -n 5p`, which of course can still be optimized to something like `sed -n '5!d;p;q'`