# Get particular line using svn command line

Tags: svn

I have a simple question. Is there a basic syntax to simply get the raw text output for a particular line in a particular file for a particular version using svn? I am looking for something like this. Let's say I want line 500 from MyFile.FOR version 6382:

```
svn line 500 MyFile.FOR 6382
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something similar:

```
svn cat MyFile.FOR -r6382 | sed -n '500p'
```

I hope this solution is clear - if not please let me know.

Comment: I'm getting `sed is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Oops. I don't use Windows but I think the `| select -Index 499` (instead of `| sed...`) should work (see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759649/how-to-print-a-certain-line-of-a-file-with-powershell )

Comment: In that case I get this error: `'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` .... And also I'm not using PowerShell but cmd

Comment: @user32882: I'm not using Windows, sorry.